# How to calculate Stock Valuation similar to how Tally Does?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a MySQL table `stock_transactions` with fields

```
CREATE TABLE `stock_transactions` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_of_transaction` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'opening_stock, sales, purchase, offload',
  `sales_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `local_currency_id` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_item_rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_currency_id` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sec_currency_rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fifo_flag` enum('Y') CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tally_guid` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `tally_master_id` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `tally_alter_id` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_optional` varchar(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 DEFAULT NULL,
  `valuation_method` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `van_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sku` (`sku`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2514 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

`tally_guid`, `tally_master_id`, `tally_alter_id` columns can be ignored.

| id | date | company_id | type_of_transaction | sales_id | purchase_id | sku | item_name | qty | local_currency_id | local_item_rate | local_amount | sec_currency_id | sec_currency_rate | fifo_flag | status | tally_guid | tally_master_id | tally_alter_id | is_optional | valuation_method | warehouse_id | van_id | create_date | update_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 272 | 2023-01-01 | \N | opening_stock | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 100 | 6 | 50 | 5000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 13:00:28 |
| 280 | 2023-01-03 | \N | sales | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 110 | 6 | 10 | 1100 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 13:00:28 |
| 281 | 2023-01-06 | \N | purchase | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 100 | 6 | 20 | 2000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |
| 282 | 2023-01-09 | \N | purchase | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 100 | 6 | 50 | 5000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |
| 283 | 2023-01-12 | \N | sales | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 100 | 6 | 70 | 7000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |
| 285 | 2023-01-10 | \N | purchase | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 100 | 6 | 100 | 10000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |
| 286 | 2023-01-15 | \N | sales | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 100 | 6 | 70 | 7000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |
| 287 | 2023-01-04 | \N | sales | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 120 | 6 | 10 | 1200 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 13:00:28 |
| 288 | 2023-01-18 | \N | purchase | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 20 | 6 | 100 | 2000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |
| 289 | 2023-01-22 | \N | purchase | \N | \N | 19621 | Galaxy Plus Pour Home Deo G1 - 16x6x200 Ml | 300 | 6 | 100 | 30000 | 5 | 0.0014 | \N | 0 | \N | \N | \N | \N |  | \N | 0 | \N | 2023-09-28 14:12:20 |

I need a report like this

| Date | Type of Transaction | SKU | Opening Qty | Opening Rate | Opening Amount | Purchase Qty | Purchase Rate | Purchase Amount | Sales Qty | Sales Rate | Sales Amount | Closing Qty | Closing Rate | Closing Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | opening_stock | 19621 | 100 | 50 | 5000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 50 | 5000 |
| 2023-01-03 | sales | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 110 | 10 | 1100 | -10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-04 | sales | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 120 | 10 | 1200 | -130 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-06 | purchase | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 20 | 2000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -30 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-09 | purchase | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 50 | 5000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 70 | 50 | 3500 |
| 2023-01-10 | purchase | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 100 | 10000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 170 | 79.411764705882 | 13500 |
| 2023-01-12 | sales | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 70 | 7000 | 70 | 79.411764705882 | 5558.8235294118 |
| 2023-01-15 | sales | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 70 | 7000 | -30 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-18 | purchase | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 100 | 2000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-22 | purchase | 19621 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 300 | 100 | 30000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 290 | 100 | 29000 |

Code to generate above report is like this.

```
// SQL query to fetch stock transactions data ordered by date
$sql = "SELECT date, type_of_transaction, sku, qty, local_item_rate, local_amount
        FROM stock_transactions
        WHERE sku = '19621'
        ORDER BY date, id"; // You may need to adjust the column names

$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Initialize variables to track opening and closing balances
$openingQty = 0;
$openingAmount = 0;
$closingQty = 0;
$closingAmount = 0;
$previousClosingQty = 0;
$previousClosingAmount = 0;

// Start building the report
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Type of Transaction</th><th>SKU</th><th>Opening Qty</th><th>Opening Rate</th><th>Opening Amount</th><th>Purchase Qty</th><th>Purchase Rate</th><th>Purchase Amount</th><th>Sales Qty</th><th>Sales Rate</th><th>Sales Amount</th><th>Closing Qty</th><th>Closing Rate</th><th>Closing Amount</th></tr>";

$row_arr = [];
$closing_qty = 0;
$closing_rate = 0;
$closing_amount = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $transactionType = $row['type_of_transaction'];
    $sku = $row['sku'];
    $qty = $row['qty'];
    $rate = $row['local_item_rate'];
    $amount = $row['local_amount'];

    $opening_qty = 0;
    $opening_rate = 0;
    $opening_amount = 0;
    $purchase_qty = 0;
    $purchase_rate = 0;
    $purchase_amount = 0;
    $sales_qty = 0;
    $sales_rate = 0;
    $sales_amount = 0;

    // Calculate amounts for each transaction type
    if ($transactionType === 'opening_stock') {
        $opening_qty = $qty;
        $opening_rate = $rate;
        $opening_amount = $amount;

        $closing_qty += $qty;

        $closing_amount += $amount;

        $closing_rate = $closing_amount / $closing_qty;
    } elseif ($transactionType === 'purchase') {
        $purchase_qty = $qty;
        $purchase_rate = $rate;
        $purchase_amount = $amount;

        if($closing_qty < 0) {
            if(($qty + $closing_qty) > 0) {
                $temp_closing_qty = $qty + $closing_qty;
                $closing_amount = $temp_closing_qty * $rate;
            } else {
                $closing_amount = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $closing_amount = $closing_amount + $amount;
        }

        $closing_qty += $qty;

        $closing_rate = $closing_amount / $closing_qty;
    } elseif ($transactionType === 'sales') {
        $sales_qty = $qty;
        $sales_rate = $rate;
        $sales_amount = $amount;

        $closing_qty -= $qty;
        
        $temp_closing_qty = 0;
        $temp_amount = 0;
        $purchaseQtyFound = false;
        foreach ($row_arr as $key => $value) {
            if($value['type_of_transaction'] === 'opening_stock') {
                $temp_closing_qty += $value['qty'];
                $temp_amount += $value['qty'] * $value['local_item_rate'];
            } elseif($value['type_of_transaction'] === 'sales') {
                $temp_closing_qty -= $value['qty'];
            } elseif($value['type_of_transaction'] === 'purchase') {
                $temp_closing_qty += $value['qty'];
                if($purchaseQtyFound === true) {
                    $temp_amount += $value['qty'] * $value['local_item_rate'];
                } elseif($temp_closing_qty >= $qty) {
                    $temp_amount += ($temp_closing_qty - $qty) * $value['local_item_rate'];
                    $purchaseQtyFound = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if($closing_qty < 0) {
            $closing_amount = 0;
        } else {
            $closing_amount = $closing_qty * $closing_rate;
        }

        $closing_rate = $closing_amount / $closing_qty;
    }

    // Print the transaction row
    echo "<tr><td>{$date}</td><td>{$transactionType}</td><td>{$sku}</td><td>{$opening_qty}</td><td>{$opening_rate}</td><td>{$opening_amount}</td><td>{$purchase_qty}</td><td>{$purchase_rate}</td><td>{$purchase_amount}</td><td>{$sales_qty}</td><td>{$sales_rate}</td><td>{$sales_amount}</td><td>{$closing_qty}</td><td>{$closing_rate}</td><td>{$closing_amount}</td></tr>";

    $row_arr[] = $row;
}

echo "</table>";
```

The main problem with this approach is I have to read each and every record to calculate closing rate and amount for any period of time. For example even if I want to get report for today I have to calculate closing rate from the first entry of this SKU.

Is there any alternative solution to generate these kind of reports? Do I have to change anything in the table structure?

Comment: Some suggestions: replace your table describing the 21 columns in `stock_transactions` with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE stock_transactions;`, but only include the columns relevant to your code (7 or 8, I think). Similar action for the table of source data. It will make your question much easier to digest. What costing method are you implementing? I cannot make sense of it. You could implement a `stocktake` tx type and use it to delimit periods, so you only ever need to calculate from the last `stocktake`?

Comment: I will be using either FIFO or LIFO methods. [Ref to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting)